# How to link c3p0 pool identityTokens and JDBC pool names

Tags: java, jmx, monitor, c3p0, jdbc-pool

First of all, please keep in mind that I'm a monitoring admin and not a Java developer.

I want to monitor some attribute values of **c3p0** pools and I found that such pools have a unique **`identity Token`** which is made of an alphanumeric string and a hexadecimal string joined with a pipe character, for instance:

```
2rxggs9vtsz4i48lg1tk|665e33d4
```

But the JDBC pools found in the **`context.xml`** file of the tomcat server shows only standard names:

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/EXAMPLE"
            jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:PRExxx" user="EXAMPLE"
            password="my34xXple" auth="Container" description="DB Connection"
            driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" maxPoolSize="50"
            minPoolSize="2" maxIdleTime="30" checkoutTimeout="2000"
            acquireIncrement="1" maxConnectionAge="3600"
            factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            preferredTestQuery="SELECT 1 FROM dual" />
```

I use a JAR to query the MBeans of a running Java process via a JMX connection.
Here the `Catalina:type=Resource` ones:

```
Catalina:type=Resource,resourcetype=Context,path=/myapp,host=localhost,class=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource,name="jdbc/EXAMPLE"/scope (String) = Shareable
Catalina:type=Resource,resourcetype=Context,path=/myapp,host=localhost,class=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource,name="jdbc/EXAMPLE"/description (String) = DB Connection
Catalina:type=Resource,resourcetype=Context,path=/myapp,host=localhost,class=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource,name="jdbc/EXAMPLE"/name (String) = jdbc/EXAMPLE
Catalina:type=Resource,resourcetype=Context,path=/myapp,host=localhost,class=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource,name="jdbc/EXAMPLE"/type (String) = com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
```

and here the **`com.mchange.v2.c3p0`** ones

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=C3P0Registry/AllIdentityTokenCount (Integer) = 15
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=C3P0Registry/AllIdentityTokenizedCount (Integer) = 15
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=C3P0Registry/AllPooledDataSourcesCount (Integer) = 5
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2rxggs9vtsz4i48lg1tk|665e33d4]/dataSourceName (String) = 2rxggs9vtsz4i48lg1tk|665e33d4
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2rxggs9vtsz4i48lg1tk|665e33d4]/threadPoolNumIdleThreads (Integer) = 3
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2rxggs9vtsz4i48lg1tk|665e33d4]/acquireRetryAttempts (Integer) = 30
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2rxggs9vtsz4i48lg1tk|665e33d4]/autoCommitOnClose (Boolean) = false
com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2rxggs9vtsz4i48lg1tk|665e33d4]/identityToken (String) = 2rxggs9vtsz4i48lg1tk|665e33d4
```

These are my questions:

1. How to link the Identity Tokens and the Resource Pool names?
2. In my example app, there are 5 resources defined in the `context.xml` file but there are 15 c3p0 pools. That is also found in the `C3P0Registry/AllIdentityTokenizedCount` and in the `C3P0Registry/AllPooledDataSourcesCount` attributes. Is not there a one-to-one relationship?
3. How are the identity tokens made? Are they random? What do the two strings mean? Are they linked to process or machine values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. The `<Resource name="...">` name is a jndi name, with no necessary connection to the JMX name. If you want there to be a Connection, set the property `dataSourceName` among all the others you are setting to a consistent name.
2. There is not a one-to-one relationship between `PooledDataSources` and identity tokens / tokenized. A typical `PooledDataSource` may contain three identity-tokenized elements. However, there should be only one JMX bean per `PooledDataSource`.
3. The identity tokens are essentially random values, but with some deterministic parts based on the host, intended to ensure no possibility of collision. (Java now has built-in support for UUIDs, but did not when c3p0 was written.)

You may wish to not have to deal with the identity token stuff in your administration of c3p0 `DataSource`s. As long as you ensure that your `DataSource`s each have unique `dataSourceName`s set, you can eliminate the identity token from the JMX name, and have stable, reproducible JMX names. Please see [Configuring and Managing c3p0 via JMX](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management).